# Find the negative logarithm of $(1+vt^a)^{-1}$

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics, logarithms

I’m trying to find the logarithm of this function, but I think I have a mistake with my rules.

What I did is: I want to take the $-\log(S(t))$

:- $S(t) = (1+vt^a)^{-1}, v,a>0$.

After applying the rules I got: $\log(1+vt^a)$

Is that correct? Or did I make a mistake?

My calculations:

[image: work]

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Given:
$$
S(t) = \left[ 1 + v t^\alpha \right]^{-1}
$$

Thus,
$$
\ln| S(t) | = - \ln\left| 1 + v t^\alpha \right|
$$

Hence,
$$
- \ln| S(t) | = \ln\left| 1 + v t^\alpha \right|
$$